# How change color of messages in bootstrap file input?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input-field

I'm working with bootstrap fileinput:

This is my code:

```
inputfile: function(id_usu){

    var self = this;
    $("#input_file_"+id_usu+"_id").fileinput({
        'language': "es",
        'showCancel': false,
        'showUpload':true, 
        'previewFileType':'any',
        'uploadLabel': "<strong style='color:rgb(65, 86, 62); font-weight: normal;'>Subir archivo</Strong>",
        'uploadAsync': false,
        'allowedFileExtensions': ["xls"],
        'uploadIcon': '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" style="color:rgb(65, 86, 62);"></i>',
        'uploadUrl' :"../../sistema/api/sistemaTareas/v1/subirarchivo",
        'showPreview': false,
        'elErrorContainer': '#kv_error_'+id_usu+'_2'
        }).on('filebatchpreupload', function(event, data, id, index) {
            $('#kv_success_'+id_usu+'_2').html('<h4>Estado:</h4><ul></ul>').hide();
        }).on('filebatchuploadsuccess', function(event, data , previewId, index) {
            var out = '';
            $.each(data.files, function(key, file) {
                console.info(data.response);
                if(data.response == 1){
                    out = out + '<li>Se guardaron los datos con éxito.</li>';
                }
                if(data.response == 2){

                    out = out + '<li>El formato de archivo no es el correcto.</li>';
                }
                if(data.response == 3){

                    out = out + '<li>El archivo debe ser editable.</li>';
                }

            });

            $('#kv_success_'+id_usu+'_2 ul').append(out);
            $('#kv_success_'+id_usu+'_2').fadeIn('xslow');
             window.setTimeout(function(){
            $('#kv_success_'+id_usu+'_2').fadeOut('xslow');
            }, 20000);  
        });
```

I need modify the color of messege:

I have this 3 messages:

```
                if(data.response == 1){
                    out = out + '<li>Se guardaron los datos con éxito.</li>';
                }
                if(data.response == 2){

                    out = out + '<li>El formato de archivo no es el correcto.</li>';
                }
                if(data.response == 3){

                    out = out + '<li>El archivo debe ser editable.</li>';
                }
```

The 3 messages look of this way:

[image]

When the message is:

-Se guardaron los datos con éxito.

The background color is good

But when the message is:

- El formato de archivo no es el correcto.

or

- El archivo debe ser editable.

I need a danger background color.

How can I do that?

I'm using this library : [fileinput.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.2.8/js/fileinput.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the html (and css being used) too, but try something like this. By your screenshot, I'm assuming Twitter Bootstrap is being used.

```
        if(data.response == 1){
            out = out + '<li>Se guardaron los datos con éxito.</li>';
        }
        if(data.response == 2){
            out = out + '<li>El formato de archivo no es el correcto.</li>';
            $('div[class*="#kv_success_"]').closest('.alert').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
        }
        if(data.response == 3){
            out = out + '<li>El archivo debe ser editable.</li>';
            $('div[class*="#kv_success_"]').closest('.alert').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
        }
```